# Porting CloudFormation to Terraform: S3 bucket NotificationConfiguration

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation

In the process of porting a cloudformation template to terraform and having trouble mapping the below *NotificationConfiguration*,*LambdaConfiguration* properties to their equivalent in terraform.

```
 "CloudTrailS3Bucket" : {
  "DependsOn" : "TriggerLambdaPermission",
  "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
  "Properties" : {
    "BucketName" : { "Ref" : "CloudTrailBucketName" },
    "NotificationConfiguration" : {
      "LambdaConfigurations" : [
        {
          "Event" : "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
          "Function" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AutoTagLambdaFunction", "Arn" ] }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I have so far in my terraform module is the following, but not sure if I'm going about this the right way:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "CloudTrailS3Bucket" {
 bucket = "${var.CloudTrailBucketName}"
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
 bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.CloudTrailS3Bucket.id}"

 topic {
  topic_arn     = "${aws_sns_topic.topic.arn}"
  events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in cloudformation template, the trigger is lambda event (s3:ObjectCreated), but in your codes, you use Simple Notification Service (SNS)

Please go through the part in this document

[s3 bucket notification - Add notification configuration to Lambda Function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_notification.html#add-notification-configuration-to-lambda-function)

Sample codes:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "your_bucket_name"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}"

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.func.arn}"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "AWSLogs/"
    filter_suffix       = ".log"
  }
}
```